# Solr search query : Given word with numbers in neighborhood

Tags: regex, solr, lucene

I just found out, that solr server can find words which are in a given distance to another word like this:

```
text_original : "word1 word2"~10
```

So solr is searching for word1 which has a word2 in a maximal distance of 10 words around.

great, YAY

but now I just want to do the same just with some undifined numbers. I just want to have a look for numbers which occure in a given range os some keywords. As a regex I would write something like that:

```
myWord(\s)+(([A-Za-z]+)\s){0,10}([0-9]{3,12}(\.|\,)[0-9]{1,4})
```

or something like that.

So I thought it would be easy in solr to do it similar to words in a range:

```
text_original: Word1 /[0-9]{3,12}/~10
```

But yes, the both terms are now linked with OR, so I find numbers OR my given word. But i can't use quotation because the regex won't work then.

Can anyone please leave me a hint in which constellation this search terms have to be, that it works like described?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this through the [ComplexPhraseQueryParser](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Other+Parsers#OtherParsers-ComplexPhraseQueryParser), with a query like:

```
text_original:"Word1 /[0-9]{3,12}/"~10
```

Keep in mind, that a regex query in lucene must match the *whole term*, so this would not match "word1 word2", but it would match "word1 extra stuff 20".  Slop also seemed a bit odd in my testing.

You could do it if you are willing to fall back on writing a raw lucene query, you can also accomplish it using the `SpanQuery` API, such as:

```
SpanQuery wordQuery = new SpanTermQuery(new Term("text_original", "Word1"));
SpanQuery numQuery = new SpanMultiTermQueryWrapper(new RegexpQuery("text_original", "[0-9]{3,12}"));
Query proxQuery = new SpanNearQuery(new SpanQuery[] {wordQuery, numQuery}, 10, false);
searcher.search(proxQuery, numHits);
```

Comment: i did it with that one : {!complexphrase inOrder=true}text_original:"Word1 /MYREGEX/"~10 --- do you know a trick that allows me to fuzzy search the first word too? like 'word bla bla bla 208349'  and also find 'the words bla bla bla 2012012' ?

Comment: in addtition: I'm using solrj to access solr-server, so  multiple-span querys are not allowed or not possible :((((